# Is 50% correct a floor effect in recognition experiments?

Tags: time-series, probability, interpretation

In a memory recognition experiment, participants have to indicate whether an item was previously studied or not. Because the only possible answers are yes or no, even guessing it would be expected to get at least 50% correct. However, in my experiment, I have people who obtained less than 50% correct. Would that be considered a floor effect?

It is a time series experiment and the 50% correct was found at the very last measurement, where it is more normal to have forgotten all the studied information

Comment: Could you explain what "considered a floor effect" might mean?  Notice that anybody who was purely guessing would get close to 50% correct, but has a chance of getting less than 50% correct.  How to interpret this number depends on many details of your experiment that you haven't disclosed.

Comment: I am not sure, I think that floor effect the minimun score that participants can get, at which point one can't really interpret results.

Comment: The minimum score is zero. What is hard to interpret about a participant scoring $40\%?$ (I see difficulties in interpreting a score of $-40\%$, however.)

Comment: That it would be at chance level, meaning the participant might as well just be guessing. But I think that what you mean is that it's not a floor effect since it can go further down than 50%

Comment: What difficulties are you experiencing in interpreting score?

Comment: The reviewers said that because one of the two lines I was comparing was at floor, I cannot really compare them because one of the lines could have been steeper, but it didn't because everyone got stuck in chance level. Their argument was that if the participants were simply guessing, they would have got half of them correct, which they did, so it is as if they weren't really remembering anything